# Screen Capture and Sharing Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-activity

I was trying to use the new Screen Capture and Sharing Api provided in Android 5.
I was able to capture the screen and display as stated in the document.
Now i want to pass this captured screen across network for sharing purpose . As mentioned in the documentation of this api we have to pass the surface object (got using the api) across network/diffrent activity in order to share the screen , now my problem is how to use this surface on other device or screen in order to display it.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks